# Derivative of roots $(f(x,p))$

Tags: derivatives, polynomials

I have a given general monic polynomial

$$f(x,a) = 1 +a_1x +a_2 x^2 + ... +a_nx^n$$

with $n$ (possibly complex) roots $z_i$ with $i=1,\cdots,n$. I need the derivatives w. r. t. the parameters $a_j$ meaning $\dfrac{\partial z_i}{\partial a_j}$. Any Ideas? Is there a theorem or something that might help me?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think you could integrate f  and then apply the envelope theorem.  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_theorem